# Winforms KryptonComboBox - bottom of active-text gets cut off

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2017, krypton-toolkit

So we're using Krypton Toolkit for .net 4.8 winforms

We're having some issues where the bottom of the text on the active selected item is having a pixel or 2 taken cut off the end, I have changed the colour on the active selected item just to highlight it in the image below.

[image]

I have tried changing the padding setting  - even to a ridiculous 7 pixels from the bottom where I would expect the top of the text to be cut off (just over doing it to again, highlight) - the padding does not seem to do anything at all though?

Has anyone come across this and have a possible fix? Maybe in-source or a property setting that I could change that I have overlooked?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: Are you using the up-to-date https://github.com/Krypton-Suite/Standard-Toolkit or the no-longer-maintained https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton ?